# Ibm Mobile First - WL.Client.Push Detect App Launch From Notification Banner

Tags: ios, push-notification, notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

Im developing an app that uses Ibm Mobile First Push Notification on iOS.

My question is how do i detect the app is open or navigate to, when user click on the notification banner at notification centre?

I know WL.Client.Push.onMessage does the trick. But this function is being fired too when the app is at foreground and a notification is received.

Is there a different function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In all cases (app closed, opened, etc...), there is a single function/callback that is called to process the incoming notification.

If I understand your scenario, you want to perform a different action with the notification, depending if the app is opened or not? Perhaps you can resolve this by setting boolean flags during runtime or assign "IDs" to the various app screens and check for the values of these and act upon them accordingly?

Comment: Half true, I'm trying to perform a different action when user press on the notification via "Notification Banner" of iOS and when the notification is receive when the app is at foreground.

For both scenarios, WL.Client.Push.onMessage is fired.

Comment: Any idea how to differentiate?

Comment: This can only be done logically on the client side, as I said, you may need to find some place you can store a value that is changed only on specific conditions...